# Search results on nested fields (within relations) in Sails.js (waterline)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm using Sails.js (waterline orm), to make an API

What I need and couldn't accomplish is filter results from a table (model), searching in all fields including nested ones:

I.e.:

---

`GET /users/?filter=admin`

`>>> [{ id: 1, email: 'homer@example.com', role: 'admin' },
 { id: 3, email: 'lisa@example.com', role: 'admin' }]`

---

`GET /users/?filter=homer`

`>>> [{ id: 1, email: 'homer@example.com', role: 'admin' }]`

---

models/Users.js

```
{
    attributes: {
        email: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        role: {
            model: 'Roles'
        }
    }
}
```

models/Roles.js

```
{
    attributes: {
        role: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You seem to be using the included REST api for waterline. I have used sails in a recent project, and I can say that the REST api is missing features compared to the JavaScript library.

I'd recommend you create your own api endpoint using a sails controller and write your request in JavaScript directly (using where and populate).

Comment: This does not answer my question and is very lazy.